# JQuery Append function automatically close Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this code to append some html to a div:

```
 $("#conversazione").append("<div class=\"col-md-6\"></div>");
 $("#conversazione").append("<div class=\"col-md-6\">");
 $("#conversazione").append("<div class=\"col-md-6\" style=\"text-align:right;\">");
 $("#conversazione").append("<img src=\"../img/Conversazione/viso.png\" style=\"margin-top:20px;\"/></div>");
 $("#conversazione").append("<div class=\"col-md-6\" style=\"text-align:left;\">");
 $("#conversazione").append("<div class=\"bubbleUser\">"+message+"</div>");
 $("#conversazione").append("</div></div>");
```

But when i see the page all  are automatically closed. The result is this image[image: resultOfAppend]

How can i have the result i need?

Thanks to all

Comment: Using Web Inspector will always show you closed tags. You need to view the actual source to see your missing ones.

Answer (score 3):

The browser closes the invalid HTMLs.

Try the following:

```
 $("#conversazione").append("<div class=\"col-md-6\"></div><div class=\"col-md-6\"><div class=\"col-md-6\" style=\"text-align:right;\"><img src=\"../img/Conversazione/viso.png\" style=\"margin-top:20px;\"/></div><div class=\"col-md-6\" style=\"text-align:left;\"><div class=\"bubbleUser\">"+message+"</div></div></div>");
```

Comment: I mean, again, this is not done by jQuery. `:)` No worries.

Comment: Na... jQuery calls `.innerHTML` property, so it is technically done by the browser.

Answer (score 2):

The function `.append()` directly enters the `HTMLDom`, so any unclosed `DOMString` are completed by the browser. So you need to make sure you give complete code. It is better to precompile the HTML as a string and then use `.append()` like this:

```
var finalHTML = "<div class=\"col-md-6\"></div>";
finalHTML += "<div class=\"col-md-6\">";
finalHTML += "<div class=\"col-md-6\" style=\"text-align:right;\">";
finalHTML += "<img src=\"../img/Conversazione/viso.png\" style=\"margin-top:20px;\"/></div>";
finalHTML += "<div class=\"col-md-6\" style=\"text-align:left;\">";
finalHTML += "<div class=\"bubbleUser\">"+message+"</div>";
finalHTML += "</div></div>";
$("#conversazione").append(finalHTML);
```

This applies for `.append()`, `.prepend()`, `.html()`. Also, these functions are heavy in DOM Manipulation. Keep DOM Manipulation to the minimum for performance aspects.

This is same like how browsers convert invalid HTMLs to valid ones. `:)`

Comment: I have copy your code but there is the same error in the code

Comment: I see the code with the closure of div like the image. So my objects aren't in the correct bootstrap grid. Thanks for your help